# How to have Android app check if latest version (as latest Google Play Store version)?

Tags: android, version-control, google-play, updating

Is there a way to check the `version number/build number` of your app on the `Google Play Store`? Do the provide any `API` for this purpose?

I have read most people just put a `version number` on the server and cross check that when necessary.

But it would be nice if I could just update the `Google Play Store` and have my app auto check the version on launch and direct to the page listing. Is there any possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this from Google. I wouldn't suggest using a server if that is not your need. You could always spin up an AWS that has a JSON payload that you can update to have the current app version.

The APIs that Google has for the Android developer console are limited and mostly around editing the listing.

Answer (score 1):

There is unoffical android-market-api. It can be used to get version and versionCode from Play Store.

You can take a look about it here : https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps